# Non interactive configuration of a package

Tags: 22.04, dpkg, debconf

I'm trying automatically answer `yes` to  `Activate sysstat's cron job?` in the `sysstat` package.

I tried this but it does not work :

```bash
$ debconf-show sysstat 2>/dev/null | grep sysstat/enable
* sysstat/enable: false
$ echo sysstat sysstat/enable boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
$ debconf-show sysstat 2>/dev/null | grep sysstat/enable
* sysstat/enable: true
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive sysstat
$ debconf-show sysstat 2>/dev/null | grep sysstat/enable
* sysstat/enable: false
$ sar
Cannot open /var/log/sysstat/sa04: No such file or directory
Please check if data collecting is enabled
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a *debconf* expert, but in the source it appears that when `sysstat` gets (re)configured it will [set the sysstat/enable debconf value](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysstat/-/blob/d3ab5dec4bf4c74b68dff930cc37e1cc2f5e3eec/debian/sysstat.config#L33) based on the contents of `/etc/default/sysstat`.

The file `/etc/default/sysstat` gets [created by the sysstat postinst](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysstat/-/blob/d3ab5dec4bf4c74b68dff930cc37e1cc2f5e3eec/debian/sysstat.postinst#L12) script.

Therefore, I believe that you could set the debconf value *before* installing `sysstat` and it will work.  However, if `sysstat` has been installed already then you need to modify (or delete) `/etc/default/sysstat` before running `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Comment: In that case, I guess my `debconf-set-selections` command is useless.